# If your rep drops below 10, images in your profile will continue to show, but you can't edit any part of your profile without removing the images

Tags: support, edits, profile-page, error-message

I used to have over 10 rep, so I was able to display images in my profile. Now my rep has dropped below the threshold, and my images are still there. But if I want to make any edits to my profile *(without removing the images)*, I get

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>
> - we're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images in their profiles. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.

Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

---

Even if so, the error message is flawed. Note that is says *"**new users** aren't allowed to post images in their profiles"*. I am far from being a new user just for giving away over 2K rep in bounties ;) So in that aspect, it's safe to say there is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: You're back over 10 rep. You can't bounty again till you hit 50. Problem solved?. Alternative is to edit on another site where you can, then save to all sites

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Make that 75 :)

Comment: Well don't spend it all at once 

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Am currently being serially upvoted. Still going!

Answer (score 9):

I guess this situation is rare enough that nobody thought of it. I'd expect the same to happen with [many links in regular posts](/help/privileges/new-user) and other new user restrictions.

What would be the alternative? Hide the images automatically when your reputation drops below 10? Perhaps the best option would be to check the images *before* and *after* the edit, but that's a lot of work for a situation which is so rare.

As a workaround, you can edit your profile on another site where you do have 10+ reputation and have the changes apply to all communities.

Comment: The alternative could be that once a user hits over 10 rep, their image restriction is taken away regardless of their rep afterwards.

Comment: This is exactly how all privileges work. Once you lose the rep you lose the privilege. I don't see why this should be any different.

Comment: @Luuklag: For the same reason your actions with a privilege don't get undone if you lose your privilege.

Comment: @einpoklum just like in this situation. Your images don't get removed. But once you try to edit your profile (the action that requires the privilege) there is a check if you have the required privilege. If you don't have it you can't save a profile that has images in it. It works just like it is supposed to. If you want a different behaviour, the discussion should benon wether or not you should lose privileges once you lose the required rep. The answer to that is a full on **Yes** from me, for the reasons outlined by  Robert Columbia in the ither answer here.

Comment: @Luuklag: If you haven't lost the privilege to have an image, you shouldn't lose it when editing your profile.

Comment: "What would be the alternative? Hide the images automatically when your reputation drops below 10? " <- Yes. Or rather, either hide it immediately, or don't hide it when the profile is edited.

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason why posts deleted through the *Spam* and *Rude or Abusive* flags give the poster a -100 reputation penalty per post [is to rapidly remove the privileges of users who have demonstrated that they are likely to use their privileges to cause trouble](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301304/336163).

If we don't revoke profile images due to loss of rep, this penalty loses its meaning. A user who has been red-flagged for answers that contain inappropriate images can just switch to adding those images to their profile page. We don't want that, and so that's why you have to demonstrate some positive amount of reputation to be trusted to use your privileges reasonably.

Comment: If you want them not to have the "image privilege", just remove the image immediately. Your post does not justify the limbo situation.